# Check the value of radiobutton

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I am trying to see on console that which radio button is selected.There are two radio buttons.I get this error TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null Should I use checked feauture instead of value?

```
<input required="required" class="form-radio" id="edit-1" name="submitted[315]" value="1" type="radio">

<input required="required" class="form-radio" id="edit-2" name="submitted[315]" value="2" checked="checked" type="radio">



var y=document.getElementById('edit-2').value;
if(y == 2)
{


console.log("no");

} else{
console.log("yes");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the field wich `id="edit-2"` exists when your script is executed.
Otherwise, use `document.ready` function like  :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var y=document.getElementById('edit-2').value;
    if(y == 2){
        console.log("no");
    } else{
        console.log("yes");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

seems to work like this:

```js
var y = document.getElementById('edit-2').checked;

if(y) {
  console.log("no");
} else{
  console.log("yes");
}
```

```html
<input required="required" class="form-radio" id="edit-1" name="submitted[315]" value="1" type="radio">

<input required="required" class="form-radio" id="edit-2" name="submitted[315]" value="2" checked="checked" type="radio">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `checked` instead of `value` when the radio buttons are not in a form.

```js
var checkSelection = function () {
  if(document.getElementsByClassName('form-radio')[0].checked)
  {
    console.log("yes");
  } 
  else {
    console.log("no");
  }
}
```

```html
<input required="required" class="form-radio" name="submitted[315]" type="radio"> Yes
<input required="required" class="form-radio" name="submitted[315]" type="radio" checked="checked"> No

<button onClick="checkSelection()">Check Selection</button>
```